# Common Lisp: Function that checks if element is member of list

Tags: common-lisp

I want to make a function that checks if an element is a member of a list. The list can contain other lists.
This is what I came with so far:

```
(defun subl(l)
  (if (numberp l)
      (if (= l 10)
          (princ "Found"))
      (mapcar 'subl l)))
```

Now the number I am searching for is hard-coded and it is `10`. I would like to write it somehow so the function takes another parameter(the number I am searching for) and returns `true` or `1` when it finds it. The main problem is that I can't see a way to control `mapcar`. `mapcar` executes `subl` on each element of `l`, if `l` si a list. But how can I controll the returned values of each call?

I would like to check the return value of each `subl` call and if one of it is `true` or `1` to return `true` or `1` till the last recursive call. So in the end `subl` returns `true` or `one` if the element is contained in the list or `nil` otherwise.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This procedure below should process as you have described;

```
    (defun member-nested (el l)"whether el is a member of l, el can be atom or cons,
l can be list of atoms or not"
      (cond
       ((null l) nil)
       ((equal el (car l)) t)
       ((consp (car l)) (or (member-nested el (car l))
                            (member-nested el (cdr l))))
       (t (member-nested el (cdr l)))))
```

Comment: a main issue in solving problems that requires such thinking and writing of algorithms is exhaustion of the recurring in the `car` of the first encountered nested element's first nested element's ..., and so on. the control digs into it and you end up with the nil terminator of the first nested element of the first nested element ..., and so on. nil the terminator-I. to overcome this i've applied an `or`. similar is done and comes into mind more quickly as `cons` since it is more natural function, in algorithms of writing say encounters of `equal` elements or specific sublists of original one.

Answer (score 2):

`mapcar` is a very generic primitive to map a function over a list. You can use one of the built-in combinators which are much more closely suited with what you're trying to do. Look into the [`member`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mem_m.htm) function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! +1 I really was searching for something like this and couldn't found. This is a really useful function but unfortunately I am forced to use `map` for didactic reasons :(

Comment: If you must use `mapcar`, consider mapping a predicate that transforms the list into another list with the results of that predicate and then it should be trivial to create your own version of `reduce` (if you can't use the built in version) to test if any of the predicates returned true.

Comment: Good point, i'll give it a try. Any ideas how can i get rid of the hard-coded `10` considering the fact that functions that need to be passed to `mapcar` are forced to have only 1 parameter?

Comment: Have you guys covered `lambdas`? If you can use one, it'd make the exercise trivial. (Just pass it to the outer function and use it inside the lambda)

Answer (score 2):

Your function seems to play the role of main function and helper at the same time. That makes your code a lot more difficult to understand than it has to be..

So imagine you split the two:

```
;; a predicate to check if an element is 10
(defun number10p (l)
    (and (numberp l)
         (= l 10)))

;; the utility function to search for 10 amongst elements
(defun sublistp (haystack)
    (mapcar #'number10p haystack)))
```

But here when you do `(sublistp '(5 10 15 20))` you'll get `(nil t nil nil)` back. Thats because `mapcar` makes a list of every result. For me it seems you are describing [some](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_everyc.htm#some) since it stops at the first true value.

```
(defun sublistp (haystack)
    (some #'number10p haystack)))

(sublistp '(5 10 15 20)) ; ==> t
```

Now to make it work for any data type we change the predicate and make it as a local function where we have the argument we are searching for:

```
(defun sublistp (needle haystack)
  (flet ((needlep (x)
            (equal x needle)))
    (some #'needlep haystack)))

(sublistp '(a b) '(a b c (a b) d e f)) ; ==> t
```

You can also do this with an anonymous predicate like this:

```
(defun sublistp (needle haystack)
  (some #'(lambda (x)
            (equal x needle))
        haystack))
```

An implementation of this is the [member](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_mem_m.htm) function, except it returns the match as truth value. That's ok since anything but `nil` is true in `CL`:

```
(member 10 '(5 10 15 20)) ; ==> (10 15 20)
```

**EDIT**
You commented on a different answer that you are required to use `mapcar` in that case use it together with `append` to get a list of all matches and check if the list has greater than 0 elements:

```
(defun sublistp (needle haystack)
  (flet ((needle-check (x)
            (if (equal x needle) '(t) nil)))
    (< 0 (length 
          (apply #'append 
                 (mapcar #'needle-check haystack))))))
```

How it works is that for each match you get a list of one element and for every non match you get an empty list. When appending the lists you'll get the empty list when there is not match. For all other results you have a match. This is not a very efficient implementation.